# Qml Setting: python solution / Settings

Tags: python, qml, qtquick2, pyside2

I am developing a slideshow but I am trying to get the rectangle to save its position so that the user can save the size of his image or text.

```
file:///C:/Users//Desktop/Hp_Daniel/QML Components/galery test/drag.qml:14:5: QML Settings: Failed to initialize QSettings instance. Status code is: 1

file:///C:/Users//Desktop/Hp_Daniel/QML Components/galery test/drag.qml:14:5: QML Settings: The following application identifiers have not been set: QVector("organizationName", "organizationDomain")
```

python

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl, QSettings



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "drag.qml"))
    #app.setOrganizationName("somename")
    #app.setOrganizationDomain("somename")
    app.setOrganizationName("MySoft")#problem
    app.setOrganizationDomain("mysoft.com") #problem
    app.setApplicationName("Star Runner")#problem
    
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

qml

```qml
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Window {

    title: qsTr("Test Crop")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    Component.onCompleted: ensureValidWindowPosition()
    Component.onDestruction: saveScreenLayout()
    
    Settings {
        id: settings
    
        property alias x: image1.x
        property alias y: image1.y
    
        property var desktopAvailableWidth
        property var desktopAvailableHeight
    }
    
    function saveScreenLayout() {
        settings.desktopAvailableWidth = Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
        settings.desktopAvailableHeight = Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
    }
    
    function ensureValidWindowPosition() {
        var savedScreenLayout = (settings.desktopAvailableWidth === Screen.desktopAvailableWidth)
                && (settings.desktopAvailableHeight === Screen.desktopAvailableHeight)
        image1.x = (savedScreenLayout) ? settings.x : Screen.width / 2 - image1.width / 2
        image1.y = (savedScreenLayout) ? settings.y : Screen.height / 2 - image1.height / 2
    }
    
    Rectangle {
        id: image1
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "lightgrey"
        Rectangle {
            x:parent.width / 4
            y: parent.height / 4
            width: parent.width / 2
            height: parent.width / 2
            id: selComp
            border {
                width: 2
                color: "steelblue"
            }
            color: "#354682B4"
            Rectangle {
                width: 18
                height: 18
                color: "steelblue"
                anchors.verticalCenter:parent.top
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.left
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAndYAxis }
                    onPositionChanged: {
                        if(drag.active){
                            var delta = Math.max(mouseX, mouseY)
                            var newWidth = selComp.width - delta
                            var newHeight = selComp.height - delta;
    
                            if (newWidth < width || newHeight < height)
                                return
    
                            selComp.width = newWidth
                            selComp.x = selComp.x + delta
    
                            selComp.height = newHeight
                            selComp.y = selComp.y + delta
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize organizationName, organizationDomain and applicationName before loading the qml:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("MySoft")
    QCoreApplication.setOrganizationDomain("mysoft.com")
    QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("Star Runner")

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    filename = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "drag.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help to other people I have been looking for a solution for days.